# Why do some airports have a non standard traffic pattern altitude?

Tags: airport, traffic-pattern

Some airports have a non-standard traffic pattern altitude.  For example KGXY is 800 feet.  Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airports underneath controlled airspace may need to keep their traffic clear of controlled airspace, which may start from a typical altitude such as 1000Ft.

As is also mentioned in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9015/524), in April 2013 the standard pattern height was changed from 800 ft to 1000ft, possibly accounting for a number of airports still having the old "standard".

Comment: Many airports have non-standard traffic pattern altitudes (lower, in my experience) that are *not* due to airspace considerations. For example, KACQ has a TPA of 800 AGL, despite Class E starting at 700 above the airfield and continuing up to the floor of A.

Comment: See also [KMCW](https://skyvector.com/airport/MCW), [KOWA](https://skyvector.com/airport/OWA), and [KAEL](https://skyvector.com/airport/AEL).

Comment: @JonathanWalters I didnt say "All airports with non-standard pattern altitudes are beneath controlled airspace" - crucially there was a "may" in there. Im sure there are many reasons, and I was speaking mainly from personal experience of small airfields beneath the London's extensive  control area.

Comment: Oh, I agree! I just think there is more to this question than airspace. I don't know what it is, but you have covered the airspace part of the answer. Airspace also seems a non-issue in the case of [KGXY](https://skyvector.com/airport/GXY/Greeley-Weld-County-Airport) from the question.

Comment: I just talked to the airport manager at ACQ, and he says he has no idea, just the way it is. "Some airports have 800 foot patterns, some 1000."

Comment: @JonathanWalters, [this answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9015/524) mentions the default used to be 800 and then it was changed to 1000.

Comment: @JanHudec Well, then, that seems to be the other part of the answer, if not the main answer.