# Why is the TPA listed on the Chart Supplement (AF/D) sometimes lower than 1,000 AGL?

Tags: traffic-pattern, chart-supplement

I'm looking at B19 in Maine, and it recommends a Traffic Pattern Altitude (TPA) of 995 MSL (800 AGL). Wouldn't 1,000 AGL be safer?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is "TPA" in this context?  I don't think you're referring to Tampa International Airport, and beyond that I'm coming up blank for that acronym.  Also, what is B19?  Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?  That would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We have a couple of closely related questions: [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25129/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25172/62). Does one of them help?

Comment: @RalphJ "TPA" is "traffic pattern altitude", and B19 is the airport identifier for the [Biddeford Municipal Airport](https://skyvector.com/airport/B19/Biddeford-Municipal-Airport) in Maine

Answer (score 2):

B19 is close to the Portland class C airspace, which starts at 1500 MSL, so a TPA of 995 MSL provides 500ft of vertical separation.