# What is the traffic pattern altitude at KSQL?

Tags: usa, traffic-pattern, chart-supplement

According to some online sources (https://skyvector.com/airport/SQL/San-Carlos-Airport and https://www.airnav.com/airport/KSQL) TPA at San Carlos Airport is 800 ft AGL. However, reading the Chart Supplement / AFD entry (pg. 205 of Chart Supplement Southwest US, pg. 207 of the PDF version available here: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/), I don't see it explicitly noted so I would assume it's the standard 1000 ft AGL. The Garmin Pilot app also concurs with my reading and lists it as 1000 ft.

I know from being a student pilot based out of KSQL the altitude is in fact 800 ft. But how would you arrive at that short of asking tower or airport management? Am I missing something or could this be an error on the part of the FAA (perhaps because 800ft used to be the standard TPA - related question that mentions this: [How do I determine the VFR pattern altitude at an airport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9006/how-do-i-determine-the-vfr-pattern-altitude-at-an-airport))?

Comment: ForeFlight says it is 806'. It does seem to be an oversight, It calls out the Helicopter TPA in the remarks and you would assume it only does that since it differs from airplanes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am based at KSQL, the TPA is 800 AGL. The A/FD er, excuse me, I mean the Chart Supplement, says "Helicopter TPA--806(800)" which seems like a typo; it's the TPA for fixed-wing also.